# No output from `try-runtime`

Tags: log, try-runtime, logging

When running `try-runtime` I do not get any logs/output. Even when specifying explicitly `RUST_LOG=runtime=trace,try-runtime::cli=trace,executor=trace`, still there is silence. However, in case of failure backtrace is printed out.

Seems like other people have similar problems: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11772

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has just been resolved resolved in https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11854.